# How can I remove Category from the SharePoint 2010 blog posting form?

Tags: column, blog

How can I remove Category from the SharePoint 2010 blog posting form? Apparently Category is a protected field cause I can't delete it, which I don't want to anyway. I just don't want Category to be on the form because I'm using a custom field that inherits Category. If this cannot be done, then how can I make the Category field a required field on the blog posting form. Any pointers/guidance on this will ge greatly appreciated!!!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Go into the list settings for the blog.
Click on Advanced Settings and set the Allow Management of content types to Yes and click OK.
Click on the Post link in the Content types section and then click category.
Set the field to either Hidden or Required and click OK.

Comment: Awesome!!!! It worked! Thank you so much PirateEric!!!!!